# Side by Side tables of unequal height alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}[t]{||c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 -- &A & B&C&D&E\  \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 T1& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87 \\
 \hline
 T2& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T3& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T4& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T5& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T6& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T7& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\[ex] 
 \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{||c c c c c c||} 
 \hline
 -- &A & B&C&D&E\  \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 $<$T1,T2$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87 \\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T3$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T3$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T5,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T5,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T6,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\ [ex]
 \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Database Instance}\label{table:dbi1}
```

\end{table}[image]

I want to lower the position of first table so that it is at center, instead of being at top or bottom?

Answer (score 1):

you have used `[t]` to top align the two tabular just remove those two `[t]` to get the default centred alignment.

Unrelated to the vertical alignment but don't use `[h!]` normally it causes laTeX to issue a warning that it is being changed to add `t` but better to use `[htp]` to give a chance that the table may be set.

Comment: Do you know how can I add a forward arrow from first to second table?

Comment: @ahmed123 replace your `\hfill` by `\hfill$\longrightarrow$\hfill` for example