# Subcaptions along with Main caption , side by side tables

Tags: captions, subcaption

```
   [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350810/side-by-side-tables-of-unequal-height-alignment][1]
```

I want to have subcaptions for each table along  with a Main caption.

[1]: My code and image is here

Comment: Where are they?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350810/side-by-side-tables-of-unequal-height-alignment

Answer (score 1):

Use the `subtable` environment, from `subcaption`:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption, subcaption}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c||}
 \hline
 -- &A & B&C&D&E\ \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 T1& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87 \\
 \hline
 T2& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T3& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T4& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T5& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T6& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 T7& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\[1ex]
 \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{First subtable}\label{table 1}
\end{subtable}
\hfill$\Rightarrow$\hfill\mbox{}
\begin{subtable}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c||}
 \hline
 -- &A & B&C&D&E\ \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 $<$T1,T2$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87 \\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T3$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T1,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T3$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T2,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T4$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T3,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T5$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T4,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T5,T6$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T5,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\
 \hline
 $<$T6,T7$>$& 10 & 12 & 14 & 45 &87\\ [1ex]
 \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Second subtable}\label{table 2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Database Instance}\label{table:dbi1}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I put third table of one column only, it does not align itself with those two rather goes to the next line. How to align third one? Is there a way to reduce space between tables?

Comment: I guess all 3 tables are too wide. Without a compilable code, it's hard to say what can be done. Main possibilities: use a smaller fontsize for the tables, a smaller value for `\tabcolsep` (try setting it to 3 or 4 pt) or both.